# how to list the functions exported by a Haskell module from an .hs script?

Tags: haskell, module

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698942/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-list-of-functions-in-a-module-in-ghci) thread and the agreed-upon `ghci` [:browse](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:browse) command, but I am looking for something similar to run from a `script.hs` file:

Say I have a module that I can `import` into my `script.hs`. How do I then view the list of functions I have just gained access to?

**What I've settled on for now**

Adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463664/how-to-know-what-are-the-full-list-of-function-availlable-in-an-import) thread that suggests the [now-deprecated](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod) `ghc-mod` command-line program, I am

- calling the terminal command `ghc -e ':browse <module, e.g. Data.List>'`
- from my `script.hs` using [Shelly](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly-1.9.0/docs/Shelly.html#v:run).

My full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runghc

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Safe (headDef)
import Shelly
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import qualified Data.Text as T

mdl :: IO String
mdl = getArgs >>= return . headDef "Data.List"

runShelly :: String -> IO ()
runShelly mdl = shelly $ silently $ do  
    out <- run "ghc" ["-e", T.pack (":browse " ++ mdl)]
    let lns = T.lines out
    liftIO $ mapM_ (putStrLn .T.unpack) $ lns

main :: IO ()
main = mdl >>= runShelly
```

This way I can pass the module name on the command line as `<script> <module>` and get back the functions, one per line. It defaults to `Data.List` if I pass no arguments.

So that's *a* solution, but surely there must be handier introspection facilities than this?

Comment: Well, there's an LSP implementation. Probably ought to be able to get what you want as a client to that somehow. But I don't really know enough details to make this an answer.

Comment: Thanks! If I go down the `ghc-mod` rabbit hole I do see a straight path from [it](https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod), through the (also deprecated) [haskell-ide-engine](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine), on to [LSP](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server). So this does look like one extended train of thought, but whether anything there qualifies as "handier" remains to be seen, I suppose :).